# How do I pull all image links from a Wikimedia page?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, screen-scraping, wikipedia, wikimedia-commons

I am trying to pull all links from a Wikimedia page for famous painters such as Caravaggio with the [Python Wikipedia module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia).

```
import wikipedia
page = wikipedia.page("caravaggio")
links = page.links
```

However the `.links` method only returns titles of links, not the actual `href` or `src` that I can use to display the image on my page.

Is it better to use  `import beautifulsoup` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import wikipedia
page = wikipedia.page("caravaggio")
#links = page.links
#for tuple_ in page:
#    print tuple_
#print dir(page)
print page.content
#print page.coordinates
print 'page.html'
print page.html
print
print 'page.images'
print page.images
print
print 'page.links'
print page.links
print
print 'page.original_title'
print page.original_title
print
print 'page.pageid'
print page.pageid
print
print 'page.parent_id'
print page.parent_id
print
print 'page.references'
print page.references
print
print 'page.revision_id'
print page.revision_id
print
print 'page.section'
print page.section
print
print 'page.sections'
print page.sections
print
print 'page.summary'
print page.summary
print
print 'page.title'
print page.title
print
print 'page.url'
print page.url
print
#print links
```